# JavaFx WebView not updating XmlHttpRrequest background data

Tags: java, webview, xmlhttprequest, javafx-2, push

I'm trying to display website with dynamic XHR (push) data in JavaFx WebView for example:

http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=^gdaxi
http://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/en/start (data in header)

and many others. Probably not only stock exchange websites.

Each of these websites after first rendering is not updating. I checked in Wireshark and some new data are sending from the server for all the time, but without any changes in view.
I was trying to compile and run in new Java 8 but sill the same.

Any ideas?
Maybe u know some other good Web Browsers written in Java?

Answer (score -1):

You haven't posted your code, but are you doing the your

```
webView.getEngine().load( ... );
```

inside Platform.runLater, e.g.?:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
 @Override
  public void run() {

   //Update here
   webView.getEngine().load( ... );

  }
});
```

Comment: Oh duh... this is a really old question.

Comment: Yes, I'm using this construction, web browser is displaying website but as I wrote data are not updating. Just try to launch any browser and display one of given websites.

Comment: It's actually very possible that the sites you listed first try to identify the browser before attempting to load dynamically updating elements.

Comment: These all work in a JavaFX WebView: http://www.oanda.com/currency/live-exchange-rates/ or http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation4 or http://www.developerdrive.com/demo/background_tasks/demo.html